# Identifying which subview is tapped

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a background image (imageView - tag 0) which has been populated by several tagged image subviews (imgView - tagged 1 - ?).  I have added a tap recognizer to the main background image, and also tried the subviews as well.  I can get to the background tap recognizer routine by tapping, but am unable to identify which subview has been tapped.

Adding the tap recognizer to the background (during View did Load):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Adding the tap recognizer to each subview as it is loaded:

```
- (void) showPics{  // display previously stored pictures
    NSString *PictureName;
    NSNumber *x;
    NSNumber *y;
    UIImage *viewImage;
    tag = 1;  // NSInteger declared in .h - background tag is zero

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];

    NSLog(@"reading from picFile: %@",self.picFile);
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:self.picFile]){

        NSLog(@"FILE Found");
        NSMutableArray *picData;
        picData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.picFile];
        int count = picData.count/3;
        NSLog(@"Count: %d",count);

        // set up picture path before cycling through array
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        // cycle to load pictures from file and place on background image 
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            PictureName = [picData objectAtIndex:i * 3];
            NSString *showPic=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:PictureName];

            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:showPic]){
                NSLog(@"Loading: %@",PictureName);
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Picture Does Not Exist");
            }

            x = [picData objectAtIndex:i * 3 + 1]; // x coord
            y = [picData objectAtIndex:i * 3 + 2]; // y coord

            viewImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:showPic];
            // find center of displayed image and place picture there
            imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([x floatValue] - 225,[y floatValue] - 172.5, 450, 345)] autorelease];
            [imgView setImage:viewImage];
            [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
            [imgView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];    
            [imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            imgView.tag = tag;
            [imageView addSubview:imgView];
            tag++;            
            NSLog(@"Tag: %d",tag);
        }
        [picData release];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Did not find File");
    }
}
```

The routine that is called with a tap anywhere:

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
NSLog(@"singleTapGestureCaptured - SUBVIEWS: %d", [imageView.subviews count]);
NSLog(@"TAG: %d",sender.view.tag); 
}
```

This correctly gives me the number of subviews, but always returns "TAG: 0" unless I tap on the last added subview.  What I need to know is the correct format for accessing the tapped subview's TAG so I can make it active and move it around, or any other suggestions as to how to do this.

Comment: This is a case where I like to associate data with the view instead of using tags and having to do a lookup by tag later. You can use `objc_setAssociatedObject()` for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure enough to say that, but I guess the point is your `tag` variable doesn't change.  If the `tag` variable is not global for the whole ".m" file, there's no way it saves its value within different functions or methods. Try declaring it in the ".h" file and give it some other name (ex. Tag or tagValue) so that the compiler could differ what it should return (the tag of a variable or your variable), then add `self.Tag`or `self.tagValue` (whatever you name it) every time you assign it to an int. Good luck and let me know if it works.

Comment: The tag variable is declared in .h, and is incremented in the loop that adds the subviews.  I used this to check:   
    NSArray *subviews = [imageView subviews];
    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
        NSLog(@"%@", subview);
    }
and the data is all there, including the tags I assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint/NSLog the tag value of your `imgView`. The code snippet doesn't tell the scope of your `tag` variable (tag++). It seems it is not getting updated.

```
imgView.tag = tag;
```

Note, the sender.view in `singleTapGestureCaptured` method should always give your the topmost imgView (subview) since you are adding TapGestureRecognizer to all imgViews (subviews). In general, when the topmost subview doesn't add (register) any gesture in those cases the gesture passed on to the underlying subviews/parent views in order until someone handles it in the view stack.

**EDIT:** (After the additional code posted)

You need to create separate UITapGestureRecognizer object and add them to each subview. However all of them can use same @selector method.

So, move this line *inside* the `for` loop..

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
```

just above

```
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Comment: The subviews are added in a loop, and the tag values are correct.  I checked the subviews with the following:  NSArray *subviews = [imageView subviews]; for (UIView *subview in subviews) { NSLog(@"%@", subview); } and the data is all there, including the tags I assigned.  Something is wrong with the "sender.view.tag" part.  I know this can be done because about half of the apps out there seem to be able to allow you to move or manipulate an image by touching it, and they have to be subviews of the background image.

Comment: What view do you get in `sender.view` (imgView or imageView or something else?) ? Output this `NSLog(@"sender.view = %@", sender.view)` . Also, It would be help if you can put up little more code, especially all the calls related to `addsubview` and `addGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: You are right about the topmost subview.  If I tap the last image added, I get it's tag value.  If I tap on anywhere else or the background, I get zero.  I must be going about this entirely wrong.  There has got to be an easier, simpler way to do this.  I have been programming in Visual Basic for over 20 years, and they made it way too easy to do things like this in VB.

Comment: Using your suggestion, When I tap the background image, I get: sender.view = <UIImageView: 0x4eaec20; frame = (0 0; 5120 2048); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x4eaec50>>.  When I tap the topmost image (tag#36), I get:sender.view = <UIImageView: 0x4eb7920; frame = (2917 891.5; 450 345); opaque = NO; tag = 36; layer = <CALayer: 0x4eb7250>>.  When I tap any other image subview, I get the same as the background.  I'll edit the code up top to show more.

Comment: Please see my edit in answer. It should fix your original issue and if it doesn't then feel free to write back.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that put me in the right direction.  I'll need to do a little more fine tuning, but at least I am getting different numbers now.

Answer (score 0):

```
//I'm not fan of this but this worked for me
//you can create new imageView and pass tag of tapped subview
//for example some imageView that is subview of a view
//first:
UIImageView *imageView;
imageView.tag = 0;

UITapGestureRecognizer *itemTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTap:)];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:itemTap];
[someView addSubview:imageView];

//in the action selector imageTap:
-(void)imageTap:(id)sender{
if ([(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender view].tag == 0) {
UIImage *selectedImage;
selectedImage.frame = [[(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender view] viewWithTag:0].frame;
selectedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"];

//replace with the old:
[someView addSubview:selectedImage];
}}


GOODLUCK ;)
```